# i try add data from my component to other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add data from main component to payment component but I have nothing showing why ?
I have data coming from the API that I display in main component, now I would like to add this data in my payment component on click, but nothing is displayed.

**service**

```
export class BookListService {

  url: string = 'http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books';

  item:any=[];

  public book: Book[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBookList(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.url);
  }

  addToBook() {
    this.item.push(this.book);
  }

}
```

**payment.component.ts**

```
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  public book: Book;
  addedBook: any = [];

  constructor(private bookListService: BookListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addedBook = this.bookListService.getBookList();
  }

}
```

**payment.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let book of addedBook">
    <span>{{ book.title }}</span>
    <span>{{ book.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  bookList: any = [];

  constructor(private bookListService: BookListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookListService.getBookList().subscribe(data => {
      this.bookList = data
    })
  }

  addButton() {
    this.bookListService.addToBook()
    alert('item added');
  }

}
```

**main.component.html**

```
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let book of bookList" class="form-group">
        <div class="product-img">
            <img [src]="book.cover" alt="livre" height="420" width="327">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
            <div class="product-text">
                <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{book.synopsis}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product-price-btn">
                <p>{{book.price | currency: 'EUR'}}</p>
                <button type="button" (click)="addButton()">buy now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**interface**

```
export interface Book {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    cover:string;
    synopsis:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same function in both components that return Observable so if you want data in your payment.component then use async pipe or just subscribe again.

Using async pipe:
**payment.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let book of addedBook | async">
    <span>{{ book.title }}</span>
    <span>{{ book.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

Or you can access all your service added items directly

```
this.addedBook = this.bookListService.item;
```